# .NET console application relative path

Tags: c#, console-application

How can we get a file in another folder of a console application?

I have an image file in a folder relative to the.cs file which is trying to access it.

For now I am using the exact path to the file, but when I ship this application to the client, it may not work as the path would not be valid on the client's machine.

Here's the code I am using right now:

```
workSheetIntroduction.Pictures.Add(5,1, @"C:\Users\Charu\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\AsmEpmReports\EmpReports.DomainLayer\Resources\Images\EpmLogo.png");
```

Comment: Maybe the picture should be a [resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984367%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) in your project.

Comment: You can try System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location.

Comment: Well, you are not going to ship your project directory either.  Use a resource or just copy the image to your build directory so it is easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft ideal is to install the application and then use the user path.

The files are then saved to the user's tree. If you cannot do an install, you can check if the directory exists before saving and then create it. You can also have the application ask for the directory and then create it where the user desires it. Or set it up as a configuration variable.

Lots of options. I would choose the first, if possible, as that is the preferred Microsoft method.

Answer (score 0):

As Gregory said, relative paths would be the ideal, but you could ensure that the file is in the relative path by performing a `FILE.Exists(<path>)` where `<path>` is the relative path of the file to be used.

See *[Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)* for more information on relative vs. absolute paths.